# Python Convert nested key value file to csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I've below file in txt format

```
<START>
<SUBSTART
    COLA=123;
    COLB=123;
    COLc=ABC;
    COLc=BCD;
    COLD=DEF;
<SUBEND
<SUBSTART
    COLA=456;
    COLB=456;
    COLc=def;
    COLc=def;
    COLD=xyz;
<SUBEND
<SUBSTART
    COLA=789;
    COLB=789;
    COLc=ghi;
    COLc=ghi;
    COLD=xyz;
<SUBEND>
<END>
```

Expected output,

```
COLA,COLB,COLc,COLc,COLD
123,123,ABC,BCD,DEF
456,456,def,def,xyz
789,789,ghi,ghi,xyz
```

how could I implement it in this python?

I've tried using dictionary, since it has repitative keys.that is not working.

Comment: text here is not regular, what kind of file is it i mean the extension

Comment: it is .txt file

Comment: A <SUBEND line is missing.

Comment: my bad ..typo error..fixed it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a small parser for your custom format.

Here is a very naive a simple example (updated to handle an arbitrary number of duplicates):

```
from collections import Counter

out = []
add = False
for line in text.split('\n'):  # here you could read from file instead
    if line.startswith('  '):  # restarting cycle
        if not add:
            out.append({})
            c = Counter()      # counter for duplicates
            add = True
        k,v = line.strip(' ;').split('=')
        c[k] += 1
        if c[k]>1:             # found a duplicated column, adding suffix
            k += f'_{c[k]-1}'
        out[-1][k] = v
    else:
        add = False
        
df = pd.DataFrame(out)
```

input:

```
text = '''<SUBSTART
    COLA=A;
    COLB=B;
    COLc=C;
    COLc=D;
    COLc=E;
    COLD=F;
<SUBEND
<SUBSTART
    COLA=G;
    COLB=H;
    COLc=I;
    COLc=J;
    COLc=K;
    COLD=L;
<SUBSTART
    COLA=M;
    COLB=N;
    COLc=O;
    COLc=P;
    COLc=Q;
    COLD=R;
<SUBEND>
<END>'''
```

output:

```
  COLA COLB COLc COLc_1 COLc_2 COLD
0    A    B    C      D      E    F
1    G    H    I      J      K    L
2    M    N    O      P      Q    R
```

Comment: Great...Thanks..

But if you see the colc... I would that to be repitative in my csv file also..

COLA,COLB,COLc,COLc,COLD
123,123,ABC,BCD,DEF
456,456,def,def,xyz
789,789,ghi,ghi,xyz

Thats the problem i faced when using dictionary..it replacing the value with the latest one

Comment: @MOHAMMED I see, it is bad practice to have duplicated column names, I added a simple deduplication mechanism. If you really want, you can strip the  `_` from the header before exporting ;)

Comment: -Thanks a lot.. Now code handling when there is 2 duplicates field name... what if they are 3 0r more duplicates of same field... how can I handle that dynamically....

for example..colc,colc,colc and it should be like col1,col2,col3 in the output..

sorry for late response

Comment: @MOHAMMED depends on the wanted format, you wan easily adapt the code to add a counter ;)

Answer (score 0):

- if not startswith("<"), save
- if startswith('<SUBEND'), add new newline

```
import json


def main():
    datas = []
    with open('example.txt', 'r') as f:
        sub_datas = []
        for line in f.readlines():
            if not line.startswith('<'):
                items = line.strip()[:-1].split("=")
                sub_datas.append({
                    items[0]: items[1]
                })
            elif line.startswith('<SUBEND'):
                datas.append(sub_datas)
                sub_datas = []

    print(json.dumps(datas, indent=4))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```